# RSS Feed with Geotags

Tags: ios6, rss, xcode4.5, georss

Im looking to update my app with RSS feeds using Geotags but cant find any examples or reference material.

Does anybody have any links with an example or reference material that I can use to help me put this together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check this wiki **http://georss.org/Main_Page** , dedicated to the subject. You however have to keep in mind that, not all feeds come with geodatas, actually not many at all. i hope this will help.